# Python: Extract time frame from string including time format (am/pm)

Tags: python, regex, datetime

Writing Python code. Below are some sample strings containing day and time range

```
'Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm' 
'Sat-Sun 9:30 am - 9:30 pm'
'Sat 5 pm - 9 pm'
```

I want to extract the time range from above including (am/pm) which will be

```
11:30am-9pm 
9:30am-9:30pm 
5pm-9pm
```

which I'm later planning to convert into 24hr format.

Things I tried which didn't work

```
# try-1
re.findall(r"(?i)(\d?\d:\d\d (?:a|p)m)", st) 

# try-2
re.findall(r"(?i)((\d?\d:\d\d|\d) (?:a|p)m)", st)
```

I'm not good at regex. Any help using regex or any other way will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  Consider this version:

```
inp = ['Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm', 'Sat-Sun 9:30 am - 9:30 pm', 'Sat 5 pm - 9 pm']
output = [re.findall(r'\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})? [ap]m - \d{1,2}(?::\d{2})? [ap]m', x)[0] for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['11:30 am - 9 pm', '9:30 am - 9:30 pm', '5 pm - 9 pm']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
\b\d?\d(?::\d\d)?\s*[ap]m\s*-\s*\d?\d(?::\d\d)?\s*[ap]m\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqlGjM/2). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d?\d` - one or two digits
- `(?::\d\d)?` - an optional occurrence of `:` and two digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[ap]m` - `a` or `p` and then `m`
- `\s*-\s*` - `-` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\d?\d(?::\d\d)?\s*[ap]m` - same pattern as above
- `\b` - word boundary

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5tyGWK):

```py
import re
text = '''Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm' 
'Sat-Sun 9:30 am - 9:30 pm'
'Sat 5 pm - 9 pm'''
time_rx = r'\d?\d(?::\d\d)?\s*[ap]m'
matches = re.findall(fr'\b{time_rx}\s*-\s*{time_rx}\b', text)
for match in matches:
    print("".join(match.split()))
```

Output:

```
11:30am-9pm
9:30am-9:30pm
5pm-9pm
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about regex, but I can suggest this:

```
str = 'Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm'
for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i].isdigit():
        new_str = str[i:]
        break
print(new_str)
```

This code is fine if you write code without them.